# How to use web browsers media player in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, video

I've noticed that videos can be automatically streamed by chrome / firefox.

If you open for example

*http://domain-foo.com/file.mp4*

in chrome / firefox you can jump on their media player from one place to another on the timeline without loading the file to the end.

Is that possible to invoke that code inside php providing the url to video from database?

I have got .htaccess that is interpreting .mp4 files url's as .php in order to prevent people from stealing not bought video content. After checking if somebody bought content / he is logged in, i'm returning in php proper header and i'm reading the file in the loop using fread function.

Everything works fine, but I don't know how to change it in order to let people jump on timeline and have videos secure in the same time.

1) Any ideas? Is that at all possible to invoke in PHP script browser's player or at least return it as html?
2) Is that possible to return somehow video link from .php file to for example jwplayer from script and parse it normally by the native code instead of creating my own parsing code which is surely less effective and uses lots of CPU power and what's more after some time (30 minutes -time set on server) closes parsing function because php script can't run for so long...

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need to add and handle `header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');` headers

When a user clicks to skip forward in the video the player will send a `$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']` to the server you need to access this and then seek to the part of the file.

Example:

```
<?php 
...
...

//check if http_range is sent by browser (or download manager)
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])){
    list($size_unit, $range_orig) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
    if ($size_unit == 'bytes'){
        //multiple ranges could be specified at the same time, but for simplicity only serve the first range
        //http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-http-range-retrieval-00.txt
        list($range, $extra_ranges) = explode(',', $range_orig, 2);
    }else{
        $range = '';
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        exit;
    }
}else{
    $range = '';
}
//figure out download piece from range (if set)
list($seek_start, $seek_end) = explode('-', $range, 2);
//set start and end based on range (if set), else set defaults
//also check for invalid ranges.
$seek_end   = (empty($seek_end)) ? ($file_size - 1) : min(abs(intval($seek_end)),($file_size - 1));
$seek_start = (empty($seek_start) || $seek_end < abs(intval($seek_start))) ? 0 : max(abs(intval($seek_start)),0);
//Only send partial content header if downloading a piece of the file (IE workaround)
if ($seek_start > 0 || $seek_end < ($file_size - 1)){
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
    header('Content-Range: bytes '.$seek_start.'-'.$seek_end.'/'.$file_size);
    header('Content-Length: '.($seek_end - $seek_start + 1));
}else{
    header("Content-Length: $file_size");
}
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

...
...
?>
```